# AGXGLDriver: glrKillClient + 464 crash on iOS

Tags: ios, crash

Just got this crash report today in my App. Did research into the matter, and it appears to deal with WebViews? Also read that it may involve Admob. The app is simple; it does not use Web views or WebGL, however it does use AdMob banners interstitials and natives. If that is of any debug help.

[image: AGXGLDriver crash] 
    gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient

```
glrKillClient

gpusSubmitDataBuffers

SubmitPackets(AGXContextRec*)
```

What is causing this crash, and what can be done to stop it from occuring? Thanks.

**Edit:**

Here is the full stack trace for the crash. hopefully this makes it easier for you all to see what's going on?

```
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x00000001989edf94 gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient + 12 (gpui_client_io.c:77)
1   AGXGLDriver                     0x000000019d4ad1bc glrKillClient + 464 (agxu_kill_client.cpp:175)
2   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x00000001989eef44 gpusSubmitDataBuffers + 176 (gpui_context.c:602)
3   AGXGLDriver                     0x000000019d4ae77c SubmitPackets(AGXContextRec*) + 292 (agxu_gl_command.cpp:93)
4   IOAccelerator                   0x000000018b445e28 IOAccelContextFinishResourceSysMem + 64 (IOAccelContextRef.c:591)
5   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x00000001989f35ec gldFinishObject + 128 (gpui_sync.c:104)
6   GLEngine                        0x000000019dc3c948 glBufferSubData_Exec + 680 (gl_buffer_object.c:1340)
7   WebCore                         0x000000018e869738 WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::bufferSubData(unsigned int, long long, WTF::RefPtr<JSC::ArrayBufferView>&&, int&) + 488 (WebGLRenderingContextBase.cpp:1174)
8   WebCore                         0x000000018e357a9c WebCore::jsWebGLRenderingContextBasePrototypeFunctionBufferSubData(JSC::ExecState*) + 1604 (JSWebGLRenderingContextBase.cpp:1165)
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d4e5064 llint_entry + 27476
10  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d4e45e8 llint_entry + 24792
11  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d4e45e8 llint_entry + 24792
12  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d4e45e8 llint_entry + 24792
13  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d4e45e8 llint_entry + 24792
14  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d4e45e8 llint_entry + 24792
15  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d4e45e8 llint_entry + 24792
16  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d4e45e8 llint_entry + 24792
17  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d4e45e8 llint_entry + 24792
18  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d4de348 vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
19  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d3b0a8c JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168 (JITCode.cpp:80)
20  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018ce018e8 JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352 (Interpreter.cpp:1018)
21  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018d074b24 JSC::profiledCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::ProfilingReason, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 164 (CallData.cpp:40)
22  WebCore                         0x000000018e03e670 WebCore::JSCallbackData::invokeCallback(JSC::JSObject*, JSC::MarkedArgumentBuffer&, WebCore::JSCallbackData::CallbackType, JSC::PropertyName, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 448 (JSMainThreadExecState.h:75)
23  WebCore                         0x000000018e251660 WebCore::JSRequestAnimationFrameCallback::handleEvent(double) + 328 (JSCallbackData.h:85)
24  WebCore                         0x000000018e60fb08 WebCore::ScriptedAnimationController::serviceScriptedAnimations(double) + 432 (ScriptedAnimationController.cpp:169)
25  WebCore                         0x000000018dce00ec WebCore::DisplayRefreshMonitor::displayDidRefresh() + 336 (DisplayRefreshMonitor.cpp:112)
26  WebCore                         0x000000018dce0a00 -[WebDisplayLinkHandler handleDisplayLink:] + 36 (DisplayRefreshMonitorIOS.mm:119)
27  QuartzCore                      0x000000018c10ef24 CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch(unsigned long long) + 44 (CADisplay.mm:1899)
28  QuartzCore                      0x000000018c10edd0 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 444 (CADisplay.mm:1334)
29  IOKit                           0x0000000189126094 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 372 (IOKitLib.c:1190)
30  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188e4ee50 __CFMachPortPerform + 180 (CFMachPort.c:682)
31  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188e67218 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56 (CFRunLoop.c:1959)
32  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188e669cc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:2078)
33  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188e644b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1840 (CFRunLoop.c:3028)
34  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000188d922b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
35  WebCore                         0x000000018d998490 RunWebThread(void*) + 456 (WebCoreThread.mm:692)
36  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000187f4d850 _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)
37  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000187f4d760 _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)
38  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000187f4ad94 thread_start + 4
```

Comment: what does this question have to do with WebGL?

Comment: @gman my apologies!!  i've edited out the "WebGL" tag to thwart any potential confusion. also edited to include the full crash stack. hopefully this can help you debug what is happening!

Comment: hello @Joe , have you found any working solution of this crash? it would be great to know.

Comment: @Ashik Unfortunately not. I've only gotten that crash once, but never found a resolution, or a clear answer as to why it happened. The googling around I did back when I made this post said Admob may be to blame, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Joe Did you use youtuble-ios-helper library?

Comment: @Ashik No, I did not. Only framework I had added was Admob. Everything else was native.

Comment: I get regular reports of this crash (about 0.3% of users). With admob removed, this (plus other similar crashes) went away. Re-add it, ad the crashes came back. It seems to be related to interstitial ads - turning off the ad unit stoped these crashes. I guessed that it occurred when the ad was rendering OpenGL content in the background, so tried dismissing the ad when entering the background - unfortunately this didn't seem to help.

Comment: The last comment in this thread indicates that it is an iOS issue https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/2mAlKC9Dr3U. Radar has been raised… https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6106840270110720

Comment: @AshleyMills - thanks for the update! (saw your response a bit late... heh!) I'm still getting this crash very sporadically. Glad there's a radar for it!

Comment: We are having the exact same issue with AdMob full screen ads! I hope this gets fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

We recently hit this in our app, but we believe it was caused by drawing after the app was backgrounded (not properly responding to app lifecycle events).  Apple has a Q&A answer on this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1766/_index.html